# How to force a specific action of an autorun.inf stored on a USB device?

Tags: windows-xp, autorun

I would like to **force** the execution of a command on my external HDD Usb, without waiting that Windows XP provide me the context with all possible choices.

Do you now if it is possible with some tweaking or registry or autorun.inf self?

This is the content of my autorun.inf

```
[autorun]
open=Synch.cmd
action=Setup RAM Drive
icon=dos.ico
label=Setup RAM Drive
```

I needed it for automatic synchronizations of drives and it is really annoying to wait every time that Windows XP index all the content of the drive

Comment: I'm not fully sure (so I won't write as an answer), but I have at same time an autorun.inf on my external hd (mostly for icon) which is executed, and at same time I don't have anymore the scan from xp. So there is a way to do that, for sure. I forgot though how to deactivate this scanning on new hdd, though.

Comment: Actually, I remember now. Autorun is simply deactivated, but it doesn't prevent icon from being changed, only the "open". So it wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between the Index service and the execution of autorun.inf. The problem might be that the Indexing service slows down all accesses to the USB disk.

Normally USB devices are not indexed before autorun, so your question is a bit puzzling. It might be that the slow-down is due to other reasons, such as an antivirus product.

Your .inf file seems complete to me, although I usually don't specify the "action" parameter, which is used only in the autorun menu that you mention above.

Below are some excellent treaties from wikipedia as regarding:
[Autorun.inf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf)
[AutoRun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun)